# bloomberg data return a dataframe with error

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I do this which works well until a create a test error (the commented out line):

```py
import pdblp

# create a connection to bbg
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()

ticker = ['gbpeur curncy', 'usdeur curncy']
# ticker = ['gbpeur curncy', 'usdeur curncy', 'somejunk curncy']   <-- create a test error
field = ['Ticker', 'px_last']

df = con.ref(ticker, field)
print(df)
```

Returns this dataframe:

```
          ticker    field   value
0  gbpeur curncy   Ticker  GBPEUR
1  gbpeur curncy  px_last  1.1698
2  usdeur curncy   Ticker  USDEUR
3  usdeur curncy  px_last  0.9507
```

Now do exactly the same, but add an error (**non-existing** ticker).

The return is this:

```
ValueError: Unknow security 'somejunk curncy'
```

is there a flag or override to simply override the bad data to get a result.

desired result:

```
          ticker     field   value
0  gbpeur curncy    Ticker  GBPEUR
1  gbpeur curncy   px_last  1.1698
2  usdeur curncy    Ticker  USDEUR
3  usdeur curncy   px_last  0.9507
4  somejunk curncy  Ticker  None    <-- error like this
5  somejunk curncy px_last  None    <-- error like this
```

Comment: that was my first thought, however, this wont work because the `try/except ValueError` would tell me the same. There is an error (or errors). What i want to do is return a dataframe with the good values...

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I overlooked that you pass a list of tickers in single call

Comment: @buran, that's okay. Initially i thought the same as you.   i would expect that there is an override.  The author of the import provides this help (https://matthewgilbert.github.io/pdblp/tutorial.html) but it does not mention error handling (for lists) as far as i can tell.

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp/blob/a591acca1c365ab49bb71ba2ac4c9587181ca8d6/pdblp/pdblp.py#L382) I also don't see easy/straightforward way to handle bad ticker. Same for `bulkref`. Probably inherit from `BCon` class and write own `_ref` method.

Comment: what i would expect is a dataframe of the same size, but with the errors to be marked as #NA or None or something like that...  not for a ValueError.  (ie. 1000 rows with 1 bad ticker should return 999 rows + 1 bad row)...

Comment: Why do you work with `pdblp` which is not under active development and is replaced with `blp`: **Note: This library has been superseded by blp, the next iteration of pdblp.. This library is no longer under active development.**

Comment: yes, i am aware of that have have pointed it out internally, but there is a tactical team that centralizes policy and the blp function in any event requires additional downloads of visual studio (for c++ components) whereas this package is available and working, so lesser of two evils...  that's why.  Plus would it work with `blp` or behave the same ?

Comment: The Bloomberg Python API no longer requires a separate download of C++ components: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ .  It is possible to use just this package, but it is a bit low-level (you have to handle all the responses yourself). Better to let `xbbg` wrap all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, it returns a shorter dataframe by checking one-by-one and eliminating the bad data. I would expect that a method with an override would be better than this approach.

```py
#%%
import pdblp

# create a connection to bbg
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()


ticker = ['gbpeur curncy', 'usdeur curncy', 'somejunk curncy']
field = ['Ticker', 'px_last']

# test each one for errors
good_tickers = []
for t in ticker:
    try:
        df = con.ref(t, field)
        good_tickers.append(t)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'error found with: {t}') 

good_tickers
df = con.ref(good_tickers, field)
print(df)
```

this is the result:

```
error found with: somejunk curncy
          ticker    field   value
0  gbpeur curncy   Ticker  GBPEUR
1  gbpeur curncy  px_last  1.1696
2  usdeur curncy   Ticker  USDEUR
3  usdeur curncy  px_last  0.9508
```